# How do you add custom text to tooltips in charts.js

Tags: chart.js

I am currently fiddling around with some charts, and I would like for there to be a string of text to come up as you hover over certain data points.

So for example, currently my dataset looks like this:

```
var data = {
    labels: ["January", "February:", "March", "April", "May", "June", "July"],
    datasets: [{
        label: "My first dataset",
        fillColor: "rgba(220,220,220,0.2)",
        strokeColor: "rgba(220,220,220,1)",
        pointColor: "rgba(220,220,220,1)",
        pointStrokeColor: "#fff",
        pointHighlightFill: "#fff",
        pointHighlightStroke: "rgba(220,220,220,1)",
        data: [65, 59, 80, 81, 56, 55, 40]
    }]
};
```

I would like for example, to hover over the February : 59 point and have it display "February : 59 - Some unique text"

Thank you

Comment: check this out man http://www.chartjs.org/docs/#advanced-usage-external-tooltips

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to customize the tooltip of a Chart.js 2.0 Doughnut Chart?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43604597/how-to-customize-the-tooltip-of-a-chart-js-2-0-doughnut-chart)

Answer (score 0):

first add this in html

```
<canvas id="myChart" width="400" height="200"></canvas>
<div id="chartjs-tooltip"></div>
```

> :js

```
var data = {
    labels: ["January", "February", "March", "April", "May", "June", "July"],
    datasets: [{
        label: "My First dataset",
        fillColor: "rgba(220,220,220,0.2)",
        strokeColor: "rgba(220,220,220,1)",
        pointColor: "rgba(220,220,220,1)",
        pointStrokeColor: "#fff",
        pointHighlightFill: "#fff",
        pointHighlightStroke: "rgba(220,220,220,1)",
        data: [65, 59, 80, 81, 56, 55, 40]
    }]
};

var myLineChart = new Chart(ctx).Line(data, {
    customTooltips: function (tooltip) {
        var tooltipEl = $('#chartjs-tooltip');

        if (!tooltip) {
            tooltipEl.css({
                opacity: 0
            });
            return;
        }

        tooltipEl.removeClass('above below');
        tooltipEl.addClass(tooltip.yAlign);

        // split out the label and value and make your own tooltip here
        var parts = tooltip.text.split(":");
        var innerHtml = '<span>' + parts[0].trim() + '</span> : <span><b>' + parts[1].trim() + '</b></span>';
        tooltipEl.html(innerHtml);

        tooltipEl.css({
            opacity: 1,
            left: tooltip.chart.canvas.offsetLeft + tooltip.x + 'px',
            top: tooltip.chart.canvas.offsetTop + tooltip.y + 'px',
            fontFamily: tooltip.fontFamily,
            fontSize: tooltip.fontSize,
            fontStyle: tooltip.fontStyle,
        });
    }
});
```

and some styling stuff

> :css

```
 #chartjs-tooltip {
     opacity: 0;
     position: absolute;
     background: rgba(0, 0, 0, .7);
     color: white;
     padding: 3px;
     border-radius: 3px;
     -webkit-transition: all .1s ease;
     transition: all .1s ease;
     pointer-events: none;
     -webkit-transform: translate(-50%, 0);
     transform: translate(-50%, 0);
 }
```

Comment: Doesn't this just make the number bold? I would like it to add custom text that isn't part of labels or data. Thanks.

Comment: where this custom text came from?

Comment: does above solution useful?

Comment: @uzaif i'm thinking the OP wants to know where to put custom text so that it will render in the tooltip.  That is what i'm trying to do and how I found this question.

Answer (score 0):

(Note that Chart.js already adds tooltip text automatically; the question above is a bit unclear. What the question is about is how to add *custom* text to the tooltip, rather than just the defaults that it picks - the x and y values of the given point.)
Use the `callbacks` field in `options.tooltips`. Note that the body of the tooltip is referred to as the "label".

```js
tooltips: {
    intersect: false, // makes it easier to select tooltips on mobile
    callbacks: {
        title: (toolTipItem, data) => {
            let title = toolTipItem[0].x; // uses the x value of this point as the title
            return title;
        },
        label: (toolTipItem, data) => {
            let labels = data[toolTipItem.index!].labelText; // assumes your data has a `labelText` field.
            return labels;
        },
    },
},
```

Note that some fields, like `title`, are passed an array of `toolTipItem` objects in their callback; others, like `label`, are passed a single object. Hence, properties of the `toolTipItem` object must be accessed differently for each.

- Callback documentation: http://www.chartjs.org/docs/latest/configuration/tooltip.html#tooltip-callbacks
- Properties you can access on the `toolTipItem` object - https://www.chartjs.org/docs/latest/configuration/tooltip.html#tooltip-item-interface
- Some official examples: https://www.chartjs.org/docs/latest/configuration/tooltip.html#label-callback

  - Unofficial: [How to customize the tooltip of a Chart.js 2.0 Doughnut Chart?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43604597/how-to-customize-the-tooltip-of-a-chart-js-2-0-doughnut-chart/44010778#44010778)

- *How to wrap long label lines?*
  One way or the other, split up your labels into an array, and return that; each line in the array will be on a separate line. If the lines are still too long, you'll need to use a function to detect long lines and split them into additional array items.