# How can I get the active label element on click in ChartJS?

Tags: javascript, chart.js

I have created a pie chart using ChartJS.

Now I want to create a click handler in which I can get the label and value of the part of the chart that I have created. How do I achieve that?

```js
let my_chart = new Chart('tot_pop_chart', {
    type: 'pie',
    data: {
      labels: ['NSW', 'VIC', 'QSD', 'SA', 'WA', 'TAS', 'NT', 'ACT'],
      datasets: [{
          data: [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8],
          backgroundColor: ['rgba(63, 75, 59, 1)', 'rgba(242, 246, 208, 1)', 'rgba(197, 123, 87, 1)', 'rgba(118, 159, 182, 1)', 'rgba(58, 110, 165, 1)', 'rgba(88, 12, 31, 1)', 'rgba(157, 172, 255, 1)', 'rgba(122, 48, 108, 1)']
        }

      ]
    },
    options: {
      animation: {},
      plugins: {
        legend: {
          display: true,
          position: 'bottom'
        }
      },
      onClick: ... //see below
    }
  }

);
```

My current attempt is below:

```js
onClick:
  e => {
    console.log("In click", e.chart);

    // find the index of the clicked item
    let canvasPosition = Chart.helpers.getRelativePosition(e, e.chart);
    let index = e.chart.scales.x.getValueForPixel(canvasPosition.x);

    // now I want to retrieve the label/data using the index, how to?
  }
```

However, the error occurs as `TypeError: Cannot read property 'getValueForPixel' of undefined`. Also, how do I retrieve the label/data using the index in the onClick function?

Thanks a lot for your help!

Comment: Here is an example an Doughnut chart with a percentage tooltip **(Chart.js 4.4.0)**  [link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/77230228/6155490). It works fine ! hope it helps :)

Answer (score 16, accepted):

The pie/doughnut charts don't use a scale so you can't use `getValueForPixel`. Instead you can just listen to the second argument which contains an array with all the active elements which for the default interaction mode only contains 1 item:

```js
var options = {
  type: 'pie',
  data: {
    labels: ["Red", "Blue", "Yellow", "Green", "Purple", "Orange"],
    datasets: [{
      label: '# of Votes',
      data: [12, 19, 3, 5, 2, 3],
      backgroundColor: ["Red", "Blue", "Yellow", "Green", "Purple", "Orange"]
    }]
  },
  options: {
    onClick: (e, activeEls) => {
      let datasetIndex = activeEls[0].datasetIndex;
      let dataIndex = activeEls[0].index;
      let datasetLabel = e.chart.data.datasets[datasetIndex].label;
      let value = e.chart.data.datasets[datasetIndex].data[dataIndex];
      let label = e.chart.data.labels[dataIndex];
      console.log("In click", datasetLabel, label, value);
    }
  }
}

var ctx = document.getElementById('chartJSContainer').getContext('2d');
new Chart(ctx, options);
```

```html
<body>
  <canvas id="chartJSContainer" width="600" height="400"></canvas>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Chart.js/3.5.1/chart.js"></script>
</body>
```